# Transform bits into byte series

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

Given a Python integer which is within the size of 4 bits, how does one transform it – with bitwise arithmetic instead of string processing – into an integer within the size of 4 bytes, for which each bit in the original corresponds to a byte which is the bit repeated 8 times?

For example: `0b1011` should become `0b11111111000000001111111111111111`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With apologies to ncoghlan:

```
expanded_bits = [
    0b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    0b00000000000000000000000011111111,
    0b00000000000000001111111100000000,
    0b00000000000000001111111111111111,
    0b00000000111111110000000000000000,
    0b00000000111111110000000011111111,
    0b00000000111111111111111100000000,
    0b00000000111111111111111111111111,
    0b11111111000000000000000000000000,
    0b11111111000000000000000011111111,
    0b11111111000000001111111100000000,
    0b11111111000000001111111111111111,
    0b11111111111111110000000000000000,
    0b11111111111111110000000011111111,
    0b11111111111111111111111100000000,
    0b11111111111111111111111111111111,
    ]
```

Then just index this list with the nibble you want to transform:

```
>>> bin(expanded_bits[0b1011])
"0b11111111000000001111111111111111"
```

Comment: @John Machin -- OK, sure. But just so I understand, why?

Comment: @senderle table lookups are much faster.

Comment: @Keith, was what I had before John Machin's edit not a lookup table?

Comment: @senderle I don't know what you had before. Perhaps I'm jumping into the middle of something here? Now that I take a closer look I think I answered to wrong question.

Comment: @Keith, oh, sorry I thought you could view previous versions of posts. I just had my table formatted differently, and I was wondering why John Machin changed it. Trivial, really :)

Comment: @senderle: Less whitespace, looks better. You can view previous versions by clicking on the `edited 1 hour ago` link.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just do a loop:

```
x = 0b1011
y = 0
for i in range(4):
    if x & (1 << i):
        y |= (255 << (i * 8))
print "%x" % y
```

Comment: And, having done that once, I would cache the result in a 16 entry lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

The following recursive solution uses only addition, left/right shift operators and bitwise & operator with integers:

```
def xform_rec(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        if 0 == n & 0b1:
            return xform_rec(n >> 1) << 8
        else:
            return 0b11111111 + (xform_rec(n >> 1) << 8)
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
def xform_rec(n):
    return 0 if n == 0 else (0 if 0 == n & 0b1 else 0b11111111) + (xform_rec(n >> 1) << 8)
```

Examples:

```
>>> print bin(xform_rec(0b1011))
0b11111111000000001111111111111111
>>> print bin(xform_rec(0b0000))
0b0
>>> print bin(xform_rec(0b1111))
0b11111111111111111111111111111111)
```